# Expresso Store with Stripe Blank Checkout after Submit Order

Tags: expresso-store

I’m running into an issue with Store 1.6.5 (ugh, I know!) on EE 2.7.2 (ugh, again!) and Stripe. For the most part, things are working. However, we’re getting some feedback from some customers that in some cases clicking the Place Order button is simply refreshing the page with blank form fields. In some cases we’re seeing errors in Stripe log files that no card details are being sent. In other cases we’re seeing that tokens are created, but not used.

I’ve followed the advice offered at the end of this thread:
[Expresso Store with Stripe final checkout page reloads instead of submitting](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18237/expresso-store-with-stripe-final-checkout-page-reloads-instead-of-submitting/18241#18241)

It disables the check for multiple payment methods as Stripe is the only payment method.

I’ve also switched from using htts://js.stripe.com/v1 to htts://js.stripe.com/v2 thinking that may be an issue.

Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce the issue so it’s hard to troubleshoot.

Does anyone have experience with a similar issue that can offer some additional things to check? I'd be happy to post some code if necessary, or share access offline and report findings back here to keep the community informed.

Thanks in advance!

Greg

Answer (score 0):

Usually when the payment form refreshes without advancing it is a result of an error with one of the forms without a templated error field.

First you would want to remove `error_handling="inline"` from the final page of your checkout template to evoke the default EE error page. Doing this should show you if a field is not being submitted properly.

Next you should add `{error:payment_method}` which will show any errors generated by Stripe while you are trying to submit an order.

You will also want to make sure that you have created a hidden input field for your token and that your JS is calling that hidden field to look for the token before the order is submitted. Since it seems that you are able to submit some orders without problem you shouldn't need to worry about your secret token and/or API keys being entered properly but it is always good to double check if you are not able to submit any orders.

If none of that works you should check your developer console to make sure that you are not experiencing any JS errors that might prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: Hi Justin, I tried this but didn't see any new issues. However, I was able to *finally* replicate the issue...in Chrome. When the order is submitted with a wrong CCV, Chrome doesn't show the error but reloads the form. Then, from that point on, even with correct form data the transaction does not go through when submitted. However, new tokens are created in Stripe each time. The JS Console doesn't show any errors. Any thoughts?

Comment: A bit more information. Once a check error (cc/ccv/exp) occurs in Chrome, the cart will not checkout, even if the browser is restarted. Instead, the user must logout of the site (EE) and log back in, add new products and checkout again. So might it have something to do with the session?

Comment: That does sound like a session issue. Clearing the cart contents should refresh the session without having to logout then login again.